# How to query latest records from a table

Tags: mysql

I have a table similar to this:

```
ID  User_Code   ProcessID   DateCreated              Remarks
1     AAA           1        2020-01-01 08:40        N/A
2     AAA           2        2020-01-01 09:34        R123
3     AAA           2        2020-01-01 10:40        SUCCESS
4     AAA           3        2020-01-01 11:00        N/A
5     BBB           1        2020-01-01 11:01        N/A
6     BBB           1        2020-01-01 11:10        N/A 
7     BBB           2        2020-01-01 11:20        SUCCESS  
8     BBB           3        2020-01-01 11:30        N/A
9     CCC           1        2020-01-01 11:31        N/A
10    CCC           2        2020-01-01 11:40        R001 
11    CCC           2        2020-01-01 11:43        R002
```

What I want to accomplish is to create a result like this

```
TransDate  Remarks UserCode Process1 Process2 Process3
2020-01-01 SUCCESS AAA         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-01 SUCCESS BBB         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-01 R001    CCC         OK       OK       NOK
```

Where if there is a Record for a Process for the particular UserCode, the column value to be put is OK else if there is no Record, the value would be NOK. Also the Remarks pertains only to Process2, where the value should be the latest Remarks. The problem is it is not outputting the correct result instead it is displaying like this

```
TransDate  Remarks UserCode Process1 Process2 Process3
2020-01-01         AAA         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-01 SUCCESS BBB         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-01 R001    CCC         OK       OK       NOK
```

See below created SQL:

```
SELECT UserCode , DATE(DateCreated) AS TransDate,
IF (COUNT(
CASE
WHEN PROCESS = 1
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END
) > 0, "OK", "NOK" ) AS 'Process1',
IF (COUNT(
CASE
WHEN PROCESS = 2
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END
) > 0, "OK", "NOK" ) AS 'Process2',
IF (COUNT(
CASE
WHEN PROCESS = 3
THEN 1
ELSE NULL
END
) > 0, "OK", "NOK" )AS 'Process3'
FROM MyTable WHERE UserCode  = '######'
GROUP BY DATE(DateCreated)
```

Sorry got confused, got the wrong data.  the record should be

```
ID  User_Code   ProcessID   DateCreated              Remarks
1     AAA           1        2020-01-01 08:40        N/A
2     AAA           2        2020-01-01 09:34        R123
3     AAA           2        2020-01-01 10:40        SUCCESS
4     AAA           3        2020-01-01 11:00        N/A
5     AAA           1        2020-01-02 11:01        N/A
6     AAA           1        2020-01-02 11:10        N/A 
7     AAA           2        2020-01-02 11:20        SUCCESS  
8     AAA           3        2020-01-02 11:30        N/A
9     AAA           1        2020-01-03 11:31        N/A
10    AAA           2        2020-01-03 11:40        R001 
11    AAA           2        2020-01-03 11:43        R002  
12    BBB           1        2020-01-03 11:32        N/A
13    BBB           2        2020-01-03 11:38        SUCCESS
14    BBB           3        2020-01-03 11:38        N/A
```

And the result of the query should be similar to this because the query should be based on a usercode.

```
TransDate  Remarks UserCode Process1 Process2 Process3
2020-01-01 SUCCESS AAA         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-02 SUCCESS AAA         OK       OK       OK   
2020-01-03 R002    AAA         OK       OK       NOK
```

Comment: in aboe query remark column is missing. Kindly update the query.

Comment: As @strawberry has pointed out the remarks for user_code ccc in your desired output contradicts the stated requirement - is this a typo or do you have another rule not yet stated?

Comment: Guys, see editted correct data and expected result.

Answer (score 1):

The easy bit is to use conditional aggregation to transform the rows to columns the harder bit joins to a sub query which works out the last id per user_code and plucks the remarks.

```
select min(date(datecreated)) dt,
         max(x.remarks),
         t.user_Code,
         max(case when processid = 1 then 'ok' else 'nok' end) process1,
         max(case when processid = 2 then 'ok' else 'nok' end) process2,
         max(case when processid = 3 then 'ok' else 'nok' end) process3 
from t 
left join 
    (
     select t.user_code,remarks
     from t
     join
      (select t1.user_code ucid, max(t1.id) maxid from t t1 where processid = 2 group by t1.user_Code) s
      on s.ucid = t.user_code and s.maxid = t.id
    ) x on x.user_code = t.user_code

group by t.user_code;
```

note I have assumed that the remarks in your desired output is incorrect given that the latest remark for user_Code ccc is r002

Comment: Just to observe that this result differs from the op's desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       MAX(DATE(DateCreated)) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Code) TransDate,
       FIRST_VALUE(CASE ProcessID WHEN 2 THEN Remarks END) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Code ORDER BY CASE ProcessID WHEN 2 THEN DateCreated END DESC) Remarks,
       User_Code,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ProcessID = 1 THEN Remarks END) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Code) IS NULL THEN 'NOK' ELSE 'OK' END Process1,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ProcessID = 2 THEN Remarks END) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Code) IS NULL THEN 'NOK' ELSE 'OK' END Process2,
       CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN ProcessID = 3 THEN Remarks END) OVER (PARTITION BY User_Code) IS NULL THEN 'NOK' ELSE 'OK' END Process3
FROM test;
```

```
TransDate  Remarks User_Code Process1 Process2 Process3
2020-01-01 SUCCESS AAA       OK       OK       OK
2020-01-01 SUCCESS BBB       OK       OK       OK
2020-01-01 R002    CCC       OK       OK       NOK
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9e63a66d1a67b7a4e481b78baf5a067d)

Comment: @Strawberry I see the the only difference - in `Remarks` for `CCC`. But the value shown by OP contradicts to his conditions - to get the value from the last record, for which `R002` for `2020-01-01 11:43` is correct whereas shown `R001` for `2020-01-01 11:40` is not.

Comment: Yep, it's intriguing

Comment: @Akina. there was an error on the query result. You are right that the latest Remarks is R002 instead of R001. I have revised the actual data and the required output.